# Office dialog API Issue in Excel Desktop Version using OfficeJS

Tags: office-js, excel-addins

We have been using displayDialogAsync popup box for authentication in Excel add-in using OfficeJS.
It was working since last week with good responsive. But suddenly we are facing some responsive alignment issue in Desktop Version Excel only.
The same has been working fine in Excel Online version. PFA screen shot for the reference and provide some guidelines to handle the same.

[image]

**Excel Version**

[image]

**Chrome Version**

[image]

Comment: Hi Team, any update on this?

Comment: Hi Team, Have you had a chance looking on this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Would you like to provide what browser you are using when developing the page in Office Online? Most of customers are using modern browser like Microsoft Edge or Chrome. But some versions of Office Desktop is still using IE as browser engine for the dialog. So we may need more information about the environment, like OS version and Office version. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for quick response Keijing...I have attached required details in screen shot on main request..You can have a look on those and let me know if still you need anything?

Comment: @Kejing......can you provide your thought on this...

Comment: Would you like to use IE to test the add-in's dialog feature in Office Online as well? Thanks.

Comment: No. We have been using chrome for online version but focusing only on desktop version where we are facing the issue..

Comment: If possible would you like to try to use IE + Office Online? It helps us triage the problem. Thanks.

Comment: I have changed IE compatibility setting and now aligment issue resolved... Also wanted to know the details how can work dialog box with chrome instead of IE Or is that default behavior to sync with only in IE?